# Get rid of PivotTable help on Excel for Mac

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2011, tooltip

Every time I start up **Excel For Mac 2011** and build a Pivot Table, Excel feels it's needed to remind me in a modal what Pivot Tables do ("*PivotTables summarize data and reveal patterns and trends*").

Is there a way to disable that modal completely?

[image]

Comment: I never noticed that. MS has secretly began to turn the pivot table builder into Clippy!

Answer (score 1):

Artist's Rendering -

[image]

The only way I got it to disappear was by going to-

*Excel - preferences - view* and on the right side unchecking **show function ScreenTips**

Then after I restarted, I went back and re-enabled those screentips (because come on, function screentips are needed!) and it didn't show up when I created another pivot table.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Display or hide a contextual ScreenTip

A contextual ScreenTip is summary information about the value, row, or column for a field. For example, if you move the pointer over a cell in the values area, a contextual ScreenTip displays the current value and the row and column location. This contextual ScreenTip is especially useful when you are working with a large report and do not want to change the layout or scroll through the report to find or verify this information.

Click the PivotTable report.

On the Options tab, in the PivotTable group, click Options.

In PivotTable Options dialog box, click the Display tab and then, under Display, select the Show contextual tooltips check box.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Display-or-hide-ScreenTips-and-properties-in-a-PivotTable-or-PivotChart-report-8ee34398-9dce-4a56-86aa-c84710c181e0